# Installing dependencies from (Conda) environment.yml without Conda?

Tags: python, docker, pip, conda, mlflow

I currently use Conda to capture my dependencies for a python project in a `environment.yml`.

When I build a docker service from the project I need to reinstall these dependencies. I would like to get around, having to add (mini-)conda to my docker image.

Is it possible to parse `environment.yml` with pip/pipenv or transform this into a corresponding `requirements.txt`?

(I don't want to leave conda just yet, as this is what MLflow captures, when I log models)

Comment: If you aren't going to use conda in prod, I suggest that you don't use it in dev either. Keep your environments the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

1. `conda` automatically installs dependencies of conda packages. These are resolved differently by `pip`, so you'd have to resolve the Anaconda dependency tree in your transformation script.
2. Many `conda` packages are non-Python. You couldn't install those dependencies with `pip` at all.
3. Some `conda` packages contain binaries that were compiled with the Anaconda compiler toolchain. Even if the corresponding `pip` package can compile such binaries on installation, it wouldn't be using the Anaconda toolchain. What you'd get would be fundamentally different from the corresponding `conda` package.
4. Some `conda` packages have fixes applied, which are missing from corresponding `pip` packages.

I hope this is enough to convince you that your idea won't fly.

Installing Miniconda isn't really a big deal. Just do it :-)